# finding the max value of every 24 rows in a matrix of a certain column

Tags: multiple-columns, repeat

I have imported a huge excel file into matlab. The file is a database with 5 columns and 175000 rows. I want the maximum value of every 24 rows of the third column.

can anyone help me plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got what you want right,
I believe you can do something like this:
(forgive me I'm not writing matlab coding)

col = 3
for i = 1 to number_of_rows
 Add the element at (i, col) to a new array
 i=i+23
end for

then fine the maximum value in the new array you created in the loop, hope this helps